# How can I insert a Workflow dynamically when an Order is placed in SAP Commerce Cloud [Hybris]?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I need to create a **Workflow** when an **Order** is placed and when the assigned user changes the **Order** attribute, it should trigger some business logic.

So far I have defined the Workflow template for **Updating Order attribute**, but unable to figure out how to dynamically create the Workflow when order is placed from storefront.

Comment: Did you want to trigger existing workflow template or create new workflow template when order is placed?

Comment: I want to trigger existing workflow when order is placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try overriding **afterPlaceOrder** method from **DefaultCheckoutFacade**, get the workflow template and trigger it from there

```
WorkflowTemplateService workflowTemplateService;
WorkflowService workflowService;
WorkflowTemplateService workflowTemplateService;

protected void afterPlaceOrder(final CartModel cartModel, final OrderModel orderModel)
{
    ........
    // get the workflow template
    final WorkflowTemplateModel workflowTemplate = workflowTemplateService
                .getWorkflowTemplateForCode(WFL_TEMPLATE_CODE);

    // create new workflow based on template
    final WorkflowModel workflow = workflowService.createWorkflow(workflowTemplate, attachment, user);

    // save the workflow
    modelService.save(workflow);

    // start the workflow
    workflowProcessingService.startWorkflow(workflow);
    ........
}
```

Comment: I want to check this the if the workflow is getting executed after the order is placed, but I'm not able to complete the order placement due to invalid cors request error [ which are occuring after providing payment details and doing final review]

Comment: the flow didn't came to the method [afterPlaceOrderfrom CheckoutFacade class] which I've overriden. although I've defined the bean and gave alias name same as  **checkoutFacade** , but the flow came to the ootb afterPlaceOrder method in DefaultCheckoutFacade.